# What have I done wrong? Calculating $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

---

I want to calculate $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{x^2}$$

using L'Hospitals rule:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{x^2}\overbrace{=}^{L'Hospital}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{2}{1+2x}}{2x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{4x}{2x+1}\to \frac{0}{1}=0$$

---

The solution from my lecture is that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{x^2}$ doesn't exist.

We could show this with $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{x^2}\neq\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{x^2}$ (I did this in another post).

---

But how do I exactly show, that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{x^2}$ does not exist while applying L'Hospitals rule or is there no way one can show that with L'Hospital? What am I missing? What did I do wrong while applying the rule?

Comment: $$\frac{2/(1+2x)}{2x}=\frac{2}{2x(1+2x)}=\frac 1{x(1+2x)}\to\frac 10$$ as $x\to 0$, so the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake in my equations.

Comment: @Doesbaddel you made an algebra error. x/y/z = x/(yz) not (xz)/y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second equality is not correct. Consider $\frac{1}{2}$. Divide $\frac{1}{2}$ by 2. It is not 1, but rather 1/4. Because

$\frac{1}{2}$ $\div$ 2 $=$ $\frac{1}{2}$ $(\frac{1}{2})$ $=$ $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Hi @topologicalmagician, welcome to Math SE! Your answer is quite terse and cryptic. It will improve if you expand it; for instance, what does it mean to "consider 1/2"? What is "it" that should be divided by 2? And so forth...

Comment: @Brahadeesh what about now? Is it better?

Comment: I think I now understand the point you're trying to make, but perhaps it can be said more clearly. @mfl's answer addresses the same point, but not in the same way.

Comment: @BarryCipra sure. Either way, I think this answer addresses the problem the best and in an intuitive way by relating it to normal numbers. It lacks a proper connection to the problem but considering I’ve seen some people just give hints, I don’t think this is worthy of a downvote. So I’m up voting.

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn thank you very much! I appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{2}{1+2x}}{2x}=\dfrac{2}{2x(1+2x)}.$$

Now

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\dfrac{2}{2x(1+2x)}=-\infty$$ and

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{2}{2x(1+2x)}=+\infty.$$

Comment: How do I know that I need to apply the left-hand limit value and the right-hand limit value? Because I can't proceed any further?

Comment: And thank you for pointing out that I had a mistake in the equation

Comment: If you have a limit $k/0$ you have to consider lateral limits. The limit can be $+\infty, -\infty$ or not exist (if one lateral limit is $+\infty$ and the other is $-\infty$).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{x^2}
=&
\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2}{x}\cdot\ln(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}
\\
=&\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2}{x}\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\ln(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}
\\
=&
\\
=&\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2}{x}\cdot \ln \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}
\\
=&\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2}{x}\cdot \ln e
\\
=&\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2}{x}\cdot 1
\\
=&\infty
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{x^2}
=&
\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\frac{2}{x}\cdot\ln(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}
\\
=&\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\frac{2}{x}\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\ln(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}
\\
=&
\\
=&\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\frac{2}{x}\cdot \ln \lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{2x}}
\\
=&\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\frac{2}{x}\cdot \ln e
\\
=&-\infty
\end{align}